# Can't read an XML and/or XSLT in Google Chrome

Tags: xml, google-chrome

I'm trying to load some xml and xslt stuff into this following html file:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function loadXMLDoc(dname)
    {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {
      xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {
      xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
    xhttp.send("");
    return xhttp.responseXML;
    }

    function displayResult()
    {
    xml=loadXMLDoc("FooBar.xml");
    xsl=loadXMLDoc("FooBar.xsl");
    // code for IE
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
      {
      ex=xml.transformNode(xsl);
      document.getElementById("FooBar").innerHTML=ex;
      }
    // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
      {
      xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
      xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
      resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
      document.getElementById("FooBar").appendChild(resultDocument);
      }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="displayResult()">
    <div id="FooBar" />
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that this code works perfectly in Apple Safari with no warnings or errors.
But on Chrome, it says that `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Path/To/fooBar.xml. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.`

And another problem is that I won't deploy de xml, xslt and html on any server.

Anyone can help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It looks like an issue with Chrome.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58151 submitted on 5 October.

Answer (score 1):

It's apparently a security feature of Chrome, the [link](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58151) provided by danny.lesnik gives detail on how to bypass.

"Try starting Google Chrome from the command line with the argument --allow-file-access OR --allow-file-access-from-files"